# Why am I getting the error "Identifier ... has already been declared"?

Tags: node.js

I am having an issue calling a function which returns an object. The function looks like this.

```
function upsertDoc(bucketName,docID,doc){
        let bucket = bucketWithName(bucketName)
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            bucket.upsert(docID,doc,(err, result2)=>{
            if(err) return reject(err);
            return resolve({docID, result});
            });
        });
        }
```

it it works fine if i call it like this

```
let { docID, result } = await couch.upsertDoc('contacts',id, myLookup)
```

the problem i have is that if i call prior to this call

```
let { docID , result} = await couch.getDoc('contacts',id)
```

the system complains **"SyntaxError: Identifier 'result' has already been declared
"**
So the question is how can i reassign docID and result to my function as

```
{ docID, result } = await couch.upsertDoc('contacts',id, myLookup)
```

does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the name of one of your results.

```
let { docID: docId2 , result: result2} =  await couch.upsertDoc('contacts',id, myLookup)
```

This, for instance, will rename the result from this instance to result2.

You can't declare the same variable name in the same scope.

If you want to reassign them to the same variable, you'll have to do that after the fact.

```
let { docID: docID2 , result: result2} =  await couch.upsertDoc('contacts',id, myLookup)
docID = docID2;
result = result2;
```

Comment: It might look better to use .then syntax in the second case. It's a visual preference issue at that point.

Comment: Yes that does the trick as i can only access the resolve object with docID and result with those exact names. I am ok with giving it a new name

Comment: @MisterniceGuy the important thing is that you don't "let ...." with the same name twice in the same code block. Rename whichever makes most sense for you, and/ or overwrite later in the code.